# Making images arbitrarily dense under an expanding map

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a $C^2$ uniformly expanding diffeomorphism that fixes the origin: that is, $f(0)=0$ and there is $\lambda>1$ such that $d(f(x),f(y)) \geq \lambda d(x,y)$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^2$.  *[The original question just asked for a locally expanding map; I've clarified that it should be a globally expanding diffeomorphism.]*

Let $X=\{(t,0) : t\in \mathbb{R}\}$ be the $x$-axis in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Is it possible that the images $f^n(X)$ become arbitrarily dense in the unit ball?  Or do they satisfy some sort of "uniformly nowhere dense" condition?

More precisely, my first instinct is to expect that the following result is true: **for every $f$ as above, there is $\delta>0$ such that for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there is some $y\in B(0,1)$ such that $B(y,\delta) \cap f^n(X) = \emptyset$.**

After some effort I've been unable to prove this statement.  On the other hand, playing around with candidate counterexamples hasn't gotten me anywhere either: the closest I've come is to consider the maps
\begin{align*}
g(x,y) &= (x, y + A \sin(Rx)), \\
h(x,y) &= (x + A\sin(Ry), y)
\end{align*}
for some choice of the parameters $A$ and $R$, then choose $c>0$ large enough that $f(x,y) = ch(g(x,y))$ is uniformly expanding.  Taking $A=.06$ and $R=100$ gave some interesting pictures, but numerically it seems that I can only make the images $f^n(X)$ continue to get denser in the unit ball if I take $c$ small enough that $f$ is not expanding everywhere.

Which leads me to the question: does every expanding map $f$ as in the first paragraph admit a $\delta$ satisfying the condition in the second paragraph?  Or is there a clever counterexample hiding out there somewhere?

**Edit:** As suggested in the comments, another natural class of maps to consider take the form $f(z) = c e^{ig(|z|)} z$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}$, where $g\colon [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ must be a $C^2$ function with $g'(0)=0$ to make $f$ be $C^2$.  Then $f^n(X)$ spirals around the origin, but we can control the total amount of spiraling by a bounded distortion result: Writing $X^+$ for the positive $x$-axis, then given $r>0$, the point on $f^n(X^+)$ with modulus $r$ has argument given by $h(r) := \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} g(c^{-k} r)$, and we have 
$$
|h(r) - h(t)| \leq \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} |g(c^{-k}r) - g(c^{-k}t)| \leq
\sum_{k=0}^\infty |g|_{\mathrm{Lip}} c^{-k} |r-t| = C|r-t|,
$$
which means that $f^n(X^+)$ is the graph in polar coordinates of a function $\theta(r)$ that is $C$-Lipschitz.  Then it is not hard to show that there is $\delta>0$ satisfying the condition above.

Comment: Identify $mathbb {R}^2$ with $\matbb {C}$ and take $f(x)=ce^{i|x|}x$. Then the images of the real line under $f^n$ become spirals which are more and mire dense for increasing $n$.

Comment: The spiraling map $f(z) = c e^{i|z|} z$ doesn't work as a counterexample: we need $c>1$ to be expanding, and then if $|f^n(z)| < 1$ we have $|f^k(z)| < c^{-(n-k)}$ for all $0\leq k \leq n$, so $\sum_{k=0}^n |f^k(z)| < (1-1/c)^{-1}=:L$, and we conclude that $f^n(X)$ can wrap at most $L/(2\pi)$ times around the origin.  Since this is independent of $n$ it should suffice to take $\delta$ on the order of $2\pi/L$.

Comment: I can build a nice counterexample if I assume a lemma (whose truth I don't know): I would like to assume that if one has a disk $D$ and a disjoint annulus $A$ surrounding it, then given $C^2$ expanding maps defined on $D$ and $A$, there is a $C^2$ expanding map that extends the two pieces. Given this, you can certainly make a counterexample: take $f(x)=2x$ everywhere and use the lemma to do surgery: take little disks in the plane centred on the real axis and map them so their images are the rotated unit disk. As long as the disks avoid the "holes" created by previous surgeries, this should do.

Comment: (Or is there some global property of globally expanding maps that my surgery would be violating?)

Comment: Anthony, I'm afraid I don't quite follow how your construction goes (with the lemma assumed).  Do you take a countable sequence of disjoint disks that get smaller and smaller and converge to the origin?  How can different disks all have the unit disk as their image?  Or do you mean under a different number of iterates?

Comment: Re: the lemma about a disk and an annulus, it seems related to this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38498/gluing-two-diffeomorphisms-together -- one difference being that here we are requiring that everything is expanding, which wasn't asked for there.

Comment: How about f (x)=ce^{(1-|x|)i}x?

Comment: So here's a version (using the "lemma") with only one disk: Let your map look like $2x$ almost everywhere. Find a disk around $T^{99}(\frac 12)$ and map that linearly and conformally to a disk centred at 1/2 covering the unit disk (so that 1/2 is a period 100 fixed point) but with a slight twist by $\alpha$, say. Now $T^{100}([-1,1])$ contains $[-1,1]$ and the rotation of that line around 1/2 by $\alpha$. $T^{200}([-1,1])$ contains additionally the rotation by $2\alpha$ etc.

Comment: Re: the second spiraling suggestion, a bounded distortion argument shows that every map of the form $f(z) = ce^{ig(|z|)}z$ with $g$ a $C^2$ function has a $\delta>0$ as in the question; I'll add details to the question to explain this.

Comment: Anthony: I don't see how the map you describe can be uniformly expanding, since the unit disk covers itself under the map, but is also covered by the image of a disk that's far away, so surely there must be some local contraction somewhere.  In any case I really wanted to consider the case where $f$ is globally expanding and is a diffeomorphism; I should have clarified this initially.  Will edit the question to say this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at things from a totally wrong perspective, i.e., you try to construct a complicated mapping for a simple curve while it is much easier to construct complicated curves for simple mappings. Also expansion is something that grows and gets more complicated with every step and you do not want to fight monsters unless absolutely forced to do it. Contractions, on the other hand, are tame and beautiful. So let's construct the inverse map instead.

Next note that Hartman-Grobman tells you that (unless you try something *really* exotic), all maps near the origin after a change of variable are just linear, so there is no point in stretching your imagination here. Take some linear contraction $T$ you know (say $(x,y)\mapsto (x/2,y/32)$) and notice that if you have any horizontal interval of some fixed length $\delta$ in the unit disk at the distance at least $\delta$ from the vertical axis, then its image under the $n$-th iteration is a horizontal interval of length $\delta\ell$ at the distance at most $\ell=2^{-n}$ from the origin lying between the curves $y=\pm x^4$. Now we can easily construct a $C^1$ curve $y=\varphi(x)$ with the first derivative bounded by a small number and tending to $0$ that jumps between these curves so that the distance between jumps is o-small of the jump location as we approach the origin. Then it will intersect any of your intervals if $n$ is large enough in terms of $\delta$. Let $\Phi$ be the $C^1$ automorphism of the plane moving this curve to the horizontal line (say $(x,y)\mapsto(x,y-\varphi(x))$). Now just put $f^{-1}=\Phi\circ T\circ\Phi^{-1}$.

Comment: Very nice! In fact I need $\varphi$ to be $C^2$ for what I'm interested in, but  I believe that can be achieved.

Answer (score 2):

**Edited Answer (with minor corrections from comments below)**

I think this answer is morally the same as @fedja's above who beat me to it, but maybe slightly more explicit. Set $f(x)=x^5\sin(\pi/x)/(1+|x|^5)$, so that it looks like $x^5\sin(\pi/x)$ near the origin and define $h(x,y)=(x,y+\epsilon f(x))$. This is a global $C^2$ diffeomorphism and satisfies $\|D_xh(v)\|\ge c_\epsilon\|v\|$ for all $x$ and $v$ for a uniform $c_\epsilon$. Choose $\epsilon$ such that $c_\epsilon>1/\sqrt 2$. Now set $T(x,y)=(2x,2048y)$ and consider $\tilde T=h^{-1}\circ T\circ h$ (so that $\tilde T$ is globally expanding). Iterates of the $x$-axis under $\tilde T$ are conjugate by $h$ to iterates of the graph of $f$ under $T$, so it suffices to show that iterates of $\Gamma_f$, the graph of $f$, under $T$ become dense in the unit ball.

Let $2^n>2/\epsilon$ and consider the image of $\Gamma_f$ under $T^n$. Let $k$ be in the range $n$ to $2n-1$. $\Gamma_f$ crosses the $x$ axis $2^k$ times in $(2^{-(k+1)},2^{-k}]$ with crossings roughly $2^{-2k}$-dense. The height of the graph is approximately $\pm 2^{-5k}\epsilon$ between each pair of zeros. Iterating $n$ times, the image of the graph reaches height $2^{11n}\times \pm 2^{-5k}\epsilon$ between each pair of zeros, so that the $n$th iterate of the graph crosses $2^k$ times between roughly $\pm 2^{11n-5k}\epsilon$ (since $2^{11n-5k}>2^n$, the $n$th iterate of the part of $\Gamma_f$ with $x$ values between $2^{-(k+1)}$ and $2^{-k}$ covers $[-1,1]$) for $x$ values that are $2^{n-2k}$-dense (so at least $2^{-n}$ dense) in each range $[2^{n-(k+1)},2^{n-k}]$ with $k=n,\ldots,2n-1$. That is the image of $\Gamma_f$ under $T^n$ contains "branches" that cover $[-1,1]$ and that are $2^{-n}$ dense in the range $\pm[2^{-n},1]$. In particular, the $T$ iterates of $\Gamma_f$ become dense in the unit ball, so the $\tilde T$ iterates of the $x$-axis become dense in the unit ball.

Comment: Nice construction! I think we actually need to use $x^6$ instead of $x^4$ to guarantee that $f''$ is continuous at $0$, but the general principle still works fine, we just need to replace $32$ by something sufficiently large.  (Also $32$ needs to be increased to guarantee that the oscillation you describe happens not just in $[1/2,1]$ but in $[a_n,1]$ for some $a_n\to 0$, but again this is straightforward.)